# Convert a binary image to 2D array or Matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing

I'm new to image processing and I'm really having a hard time understanding stuff...so the idea is that how do you create a matrix from a binary image in python?

[image]

to something like this:

[image]

It not the same image though the point is there.
Thank you for helping, I appreciate it cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using cv2**  -Read more [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('path/to/img.jpg')
resized = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
print pic
```

**Using skimage** - Read more [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html)

```
import skimage.io as skio
faces = skio.imread_collection('path/to/images/*.pgm',conserve_memory=True) # can load multiple images at once
```

**Using Scipy** - Read more [here](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/)

```
from scipy import misc
pic = misc.imread('path/to/img.jpg')
print pic
```

**Plotting Images**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(faces[0],cmap=plt.cm.gray_r,interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

## example I am currently working with.

```
"""
A set of utilities that are helpful for working with images. These are utilities
needed to actually apply the seam carving algorithm to images
"""


from PIL import Image


class Color:
    """
    A simple class representing an RGB value.
    """

    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Color({self.r}, {self.g}, {self.b})'

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)


def read_image_into_array(filename):
    """
    Read the given image into a 2D array of pixels. The result is an array,
    where each element represents a row. Each row is an array, where each
    element is a color.

    See: Color
    """

    img = Image.open(filename, 'r')
    w, h = img.size

    pixels = list(Color(*pixel) for pixel in img.getdata())
    return [pixels[n:(n + w)] for n in range(0, w * h, w)]


def write_array_into_image(pixels, filename):
    """
    Write the given 2D array of pixels into an image with the given filename.
    The input pixels are represented as an array, where each element is a row.
    Each row is an array, where each element is a color.

    See: Color
    """

    h = len(pixels)
    w = len(pixels[0])

    img = Image.new('RGB', (w, h))

    output_pixels = img.load()
    for y, row in enumerate(pixels):
        for x, color in enumerate(row):
            output_pixels[x, y] = (color.r, color.g, color.b)

    img.save(filename)
```